# How to use query data for another sql query in yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

I have a query here:

```
  public function SearchExactJob($id) {
      $connect = \Yii::$app->db;

      $query = $connect->createCommand('
           SELECT job_name FROM job_questions WHERE job_id=:id')
           ->bindValue(':id':$id)
           ->queryAll();

}
```

I want to use the `job_name` for another query: **PS: I just wrote this down on a paper in case i'll be able to find out how to get this data**

```
  $anotherquery = $connect->createCommand(
                  'SELECT * FROM company_questions
                   WHERE company_question = [the job_name I want to get from the `$query`])
```

Also if I will successfully get the `$anotherquery` work, I want to get the data and pass it on the view assigned to this.

But then, im asking for help because I just recently used Yii2. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this one.

```
     $query=$connect->createCommand('
       SELECT job_name FROM job_questions WHERE job_id=:id')
       ->bindValue(':id':$id)
       ->queryOne(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

add the data on a variable: ex. `$job_name`

`$job_name = $query->job_name;`

Answer (score 0):

get Jobs Name

```
public function SearchExactJob($id) {
  $connect = \Yii::$app->db;

  $query = $connect->createCommand('
       SELECT job_name FROM job_questions WHERE job_id=:id')
       ->bindValue(':id':$id)
       ->asArray()
       ->queryAll();
}
```

Above code will return  two-dimesional array. Convert two dimensional array to one-dimensional array

```
 $jobs = array_map('current',$query);
```

Finally you can use **where in** clause to search for jobs.

```
$anotherquery = $connect->createCommand(
              'SELECT * FROM company_questions
               WHERE IN $jobs)
```

I highly recommend you to use active record when querying data, less syntax error and more easily readable.

Comment: Hi, thanks. your answer is appreciated but i've got this solved already. I've updated my question with the answer. :)